# error in pandas dataframe when trying to convert dtype object to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to aggregate data converted from an xlsx file to a dataframe but it is all dtype object.
I tried to convert it to strings and float so I can aggregate it but this is the error I get :

```
SystemError: <class 'UnicodeEncodeError'> returned a result with an error set
```

This is my code :

```
new_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(new_df['Date'])
new_df[['Country', 'City', 'Specie']] = new_df[['Country', 'City', 'Specie']].astype('|S80')
new_df[['count', 'min', 'max', 'median', 'variance']] = pd.to_numeric(new_df[['count', 'min', 'max', 'median', 'variance']],errors='coerce')
```

This is a sample of the dataframe :

```
         Date Country       City Specie count   min   max median variance
   2020-02-23      CR  San JosÃ©   pm25    20  13.0  53.0   25.0  1232.00
   2020-04-04      CR  San JosÃ©   pm25    23  17.0  57.0   38.0  1302.57
   2020-04-24      CR  San JosÃ©   pm25    23  30.0  80.0   59.0  1966.13
   2020-01-14      CR  San JosÃ©   pm25    24  13.0  34.0   21.0   379.55
   2020-02-07      CR  San JosÃ©   pm25    23  57.0  95.0   72.0   838.97
```

Comment: You can try this `df['City'].str.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: I realized its an excel file and the encoding is hexadecimal

Answer (score 1):

should check how ".csv file" is encoded first.

If that csv file is encoded as"utf-8", try this

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: tried this but realized it's an xlsx file sorry! should I convert my excel file into a csv or is there something else I can do?

Comment: pd.read_excel(file, encoding="utf-8")
please you have to check that your excel file is encoded as utf-8

Comment: the encoding is hexadecimal